# Send and Receive SOAP api from PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soap-client

I am trying to get a valid request and get a response from a SOAP web service.
the request works fine from SOAPUI but when I try to initiate a request from within my PHP file, it returns invalid credentials. I have tried to use the curl example but is there a better way to go about it? there is a username and password on the documentation, I want to know if this is also expected to be passed through the code or not.

my request code:

```
<?php
$webservice_url = 'https://rsaauthweb.mtn.com.ng/AuthServices/RSAServices?WSDL';    

$tokenData = '666';
$key = 'fgghhj6T1E54567';
/**
$data = openssl_encrypt($tokenData, 'AES-128-ECB', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
$tokencode = utf8_encode(bin2hex($data));
**/
$tokenData = utf8_encode($tokenData);
$key = utf8_encode($key);
$data = openssl_encrypt($tokenData, 'AES-128-ECB', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
$tokencode = base64_encode($data);


$userId = 'faketest';
//$tokencode = 'fakecode';//'12345678';
echo $tokencode."<br>";
$request_param = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.mtn.rsa.jojief.com/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<ser:authenticateUser>
<request>
<userId>'.$userId.'</userId>
<passcode>'.$tokencode.'</passcode>
</request>
</ser:authenticateUser>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';


/** $request_param2 = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://service.mtn.rsa.jojief.com/">
 
<soapenv:Header/>
 
<soapenv:Body>
   
<ser:authenticateUser>
   
<request>
   
<passcode>fakecode</passcode>
     
<userId>"faketest"</userId>
     
</request>
   
</ser:authenticateUser>
 
</soapenv:Body>

</soapenv:Envelope>';
**/

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($request_param)
);

$ch = curl_init($webservice_url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_param);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$data = curl_exec ($ch);

$result = $data;

if ($result === FALSE) {
    printf("CURL error (#%d): %s<br>\n", curl_errno($ch),
    htmlspecialchars(curl_error($ch)));
}else{
echo $data;
}

curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

why am I getting invalid credentials?

Answer (score 0):

i got a way to resolve it, you have to encode the username and password and pass it as header

```
'''<?php

$url = "https://rsaauthweb.ntn.com.ng/AuthServices/RSAServices?WSDL";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
"Content-Type: text/xml",
"Authorization: Basic bXRuOlBAITM0NVlV",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = <<<DATA
<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ser="http://service.ntn.rsa.jojief.com/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <ser:authenticateUser>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <request>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <passcode>passcode</passcode>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <userId>username</userId>
     </request>
  </ser:authenticateUser>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
DATA;

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);

?>'''
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).